# Android build - jar command not found

Tags: android, build, jar, command

I'm trying to build Android and when I get to the point of "make" I get an error saying "...jar: command not found". I've installed Java SE 1.6 and verified it works correctly and that the jar executable is in the appropriate folder. But still I get this error. A little help...

Comment: go to this link  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571656/jar-command-not-found-how-to-resolve-this-error"

Comment: I've already seen this. That's why I asked it again. echo $PATH displays the path of java/bin dir

Comment: Then try to reinstall jdk by another way.